# Setting up subclipse with existing project with multiple SVN checked-out folders

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm having troubles getting SVN functionality added to my PyDev project.

I've set it up as:

- workdir
- workdir/project_x
- workdir/project_y
- workdir/project_z

Each of those projext_ folders is a specific checkout folder from different SVN repositories.

The workdir itself is imported in Eclipse as a PyDev project.

I've tried with Subclipse:

- Renaming project
- Using the 'team/share' functionality. It says it found the .svn in each of the project folders and wants to delete them. The next step is to setup a SVN url, but I have multiple.

Anyone got a clue how to get subclipse working?

(I've setup these folder because of problem with python finding components in the other project folders.)

Running on Ubuntu (if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse team connection can only be made at the top Eclipse project level, or at least that is all Subclipse can do.

You could possibly connect workdir to a local file:// repos and then set the svn:external property to have it pull in the different projects. Subclipse would support that ok.